# Jmeter performance measurement - kibana dashboard url

Tags: performance, jmeter, kibana

I am looking for help in performance measurement of Kibana dashboard through jmeter

Kibana is one of the product of elastic search.
https://www.elastic.co/products/kibana

When we ran jmeter with kibana dashboard url, it is not giving appropriate result. because whenever we load kibana, it has a kind of intermediate page, and then the actual dashboard loads.

Jmeter measures performance with the intermediate page itself, where as it is not waiting for the entire kibana dashboard to load.

anybody has tried on this scenario

Comment: did u record all requests from the browser via jmeter recorder?

Comment: yes i have tried recording the sequence and recorded the playback of the same. the problem i am facing now is...  there are some 20 requests my dashboard is sending internally.

when i did play back with 5 loopcount, there are few request was sent 4th time whereas other requests are sent only 2 times.  in that case how to believe the performance data.

ideally it should follow the same sequence or all request should have completed in the particular time before it sends 2nd set of requests.

Comment: Please update your question with this information. Also if you could publish your test plan outline, to see what jmeter elements you are using/not-using.

Comment: now i could able to resolve it...i have segregated the number of requests it sent and i could able to get the performance data almost similar to the manual request. thanks user1697575 for replying to my query...

Answer (score 0):

Based on the described issue, you should use [Synchronizing Timer](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Synchronizing_Timer) that can make sure you are not firing your requests out of order.

[image]